# Leaving field blank but showing a start hour?

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am trying to set up start times for the day. When the time picker shows, it keeps saying 12 : 00 AM. I want the times to start at 10 : 00 AM, and increment by 30 minutes. I am using `enabledHours` to limit the input. I am also using `useCurrent: false` so that the input field is empty when the page is loaded.

Basically am using this:

```
format: 'LT',
stepping: 30,
enabledHours: [10, 11, . . . 19],
minDate: moment().hour(10),
useCurrent: false,
showClose: true,
allowInputToggle: true
```

I have a separate input for the date, all I want to show is the time.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to set starting date for datetime picker is using [`defaultDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) option. Setting this option, the picker input field will be populated with the given date, as you can see in the live example:

```js
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
  format: 'LT',
  stepping: 30,
  minDate: moment({hour: 10}),
  maxDate: moment({hour: 19, minutes: 30}),
  defaultDate: moment({hour: 10}),
  useCurrent: false,
  showClose: true,
  allowInputToggle: true
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

If the input has to be initally blank, then you have to do something a little bit complex. You can listen for [`dp.show`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpshow) event and set a given date (using [`date`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method) if no previous date was set.

Here a live working example:

```js
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
  format: 'LT',
  stepping: 30,
  minDate: moment({hour: 10}),
  maxDate: moment({hour: 19, minutes: 30}),
  useCurrent: false,
  showClose: true,
  allowInputToggle: true
}).on('dp.show', function(){
  var date = $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date();
  if( !date ){
    var defaultDate = moment({hour: 10});
    $(this).data("DateTimePicker").date(defaultDate);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

Please note that I used [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) and [`maxDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) instead of [`enabledHours`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enabledhours), since you are selecting only time. Moreover I used `moment({hour: 10})` instead of `moment().hour(10)` because the first ([`moment({unit: value, ...});`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/)) defaults to 0 for minutes, seconds, milliseconds while the latter takes in account current minutes, seconds etc.

Comment: Thanks, @VincenzoC, that was extremely helpful!